# No css , js, image file is loading on the website. My website is based on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

My index.php file is in pubic_html and all other folders such as application , assets , system are there. They each have sub folders and files. I am trying to restore a website based on codeigniter and I have followed there installation guid but there is an issue with the css files.

On the wesbite there is only text but no css and no images.

Here is an example of how link is written in the files.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url();assets/img/logo.png">
```

[image: here it is in the browser]

This code is in my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^=]+=.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^=]+=.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am attaching the screen shots of the website and issue I am facing.I have tried everything. If anyone could help that would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: My website is showing like this]

Comment: What is your `.htaccess` like?

Comment: 'RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^=]+=.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^=]+=.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]'

Comment: this is the code written in my htacess

Comment: Please insert it in your post directly.

Comment: Make sure you have set the base url in the config.php example  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/'` and also `<?php echo base_url('assets/img/logo.png');?>"`

Comment: How about an example of the generated code in your HTML page - by viewing the HTML source in your Browser. What is the actual output?

Answer (score 1):

I have found my solution: 
Basically I have to change the config.php file force the URI_request
https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/